# Git getting back deleted directory

Tags: git

I had a problem with Git, and wanted to recommit a certain commit. 
But i didn't read the instructions well and lost my directory from my local environment. How can I get it back?

```
git log --oneline
592d36e Revert "Adding periodontogramma and job_management support"
dc477b8 Added django rest framework requirement
1f0f4ea Adding periodontogramma and job_management support this is the one I reverted and deleted my directory.
```

Can I do this?

```
git checkout 592d36e
```

Will it bring back my directories and files deleted?

EDIT: after getting my directories back now I get this

```
 git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --all
* 592d36e (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) Revert "Adding periodontogramma a
* dc477b8 Added django rest framework requirement
* 1f0f4ea (HEAD) Adding periodontogramma and job_management support
```

How can I recommit changes in 1f0f4ea and get this HEAD detached message out of the way. My remote repo is missing files that I allready have on my local

Comment: did you commit after deletion? make sure you are also in the same branch

Comment: In addition, had you committed the directory before deletion? And could you please clarify the steps that lead you to lose the directory?

Comment: I did git checout 1f0f4ea and then git commit and my directories were back

Comment: Still my local repo and remote repo (on openshift) are different. How do I sync them (so the remote repo has the files that are missing)?

Comment: I'm not exactly a git expert but my limited knowledge tells me to commit + push otherwise the files/dirs will be pulled on the next checkout/pull - always talking on the same branch

Comment: git commit tells my that there is nothing to commit and that wokring directory is clear. Also git push tells me everything is up-to date

Answer (score 0):

Even easier, just revert your revert! If you've made no changes or commits since you ran the revert, just use `git revert HEAD` to undo the last commit (which, in this case, is the revert).

Comment: by HEAD means the first commit on the list produced by git log --oneline?

Comment: Sort of. HEAD normally refers to the latest commit of the current branch, however by checking out a specific commit instead of a branch, you can enter a "Detached HEAD" state, where your local HEAD is pointing to a revision that isn't associated with a branch name. `git log` doesn't print it, but I use `git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --all` (aliased so I don't have to type it all out) which will show, among other things, the HEAD of your working tree and the HEAD of each branch.

Comment: Based on what you said you did in the comments to your post, in order for this to work, you'll need to run `git checkout master` (assuming you're on master branch) and then `git revert HEAD` (though I'd recommend using the log command I posted above to make sure HEAD is in the right place). That will create a new commit which will let you push to your server and undo the other revert.

Comment: edited my initial post. Will your commands help me get in place or will the delete my local directories too?

Comment: You can see from the HEAD location (at commit 1f0f4ea) that your head is detached. That means that you aren't on any branch and any commits you make aren't being tracked. If you really want, you can create a new branch at your current location and start again from commit 1f0f4ea, or you can run the two commands I gave in my previous comment and that should fix it. The first one (`git checkout master`) will reset your working tree to the HEAD of master (which is the accidental revert). The second one (`git revert HEAD`) will revert that commit, creating a new revert commit which you can push.

Comment: thank you...git checout master and git revert HEAD was the solution @Eric. You saved my life!!